# GoogleMapsv2 para de funcionar na versão de produção

Tags: android, google-maps

Meu app funciona com Google Maps perfeitamente na versão de debug, mas quando eu publico na Play Store ele para de funcionar.

Qual o processo para gerar a hash do GoogleMapsV2 para a versão release?
Como testar o .apk, antes do upload, para ter certeza que o GoogleMapsV2 irá funcionar?

Comment: Qual IDE você utiliza?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues Eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando a IDE Eclipse, você pode gerar o hash no momento que você exportar seu projeto para um APK acessando **File > Export**, selecionando **Export Android Application** e na tela seguindo o seu projeto, você terá algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de gerado, na última tela você verá um **"Certificate fingerprints"**, que são em MD5 e SHA1.

Com este *SHA1*, basta você acessar o seu **[Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com)**, no seu projeto e adicionar este *fingerprint* na credencial **"Key for Android applications"** já existente, que você utiliza para o modo debug. Lembrando que não precisa criar outra credencial, basta adicionar uma nova linha com este *SHA1* gerado para produção.

Pra você testar esse **APK**, é só instalar em seu aparelho que ele já possui a nova **keystore** de produção, a mesma que você vai utilizar na *Play*.

Answer (score 0):

Também tive o mesmo problema, descubri que a solução deste problema é usar uma KEY publica para quando alguém fizer o download da app conseguir utilizar o GMaps. Para isso basta procurar no google developers console que tem la um tutorial para colocar o serviço aberto.