# Google api v2, já tenho a chave, porém, fornecido por terceiros, como habilitar sem SHA-1?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google, google-maps-android-api-2

Eu tenho uma chave para habilitar o **Google Maps V2** no android, fiz tudo que tinha que fazer no Manifest e no Gradle, ao rodar a plicação, aparece o Fragment com nome Google, porém, não carrega nada, fica na cor Bege claro, sem nada na tela, porém, a chave eu recebi por e-mail da empresa, onde a mesma comprou a licença e me enviou a chave, sou novo com o Google Maps e percebi que para gerar a chave é necessário ter o **SHA-1** do seu PC que está desenvolvendo, estou me orientando pelo livro **GOOGLE ANDROID** *3ª edição* da editora *Novatec*, e nela explica que para acessar os serviços da Google pelo cloud.google.com eu precisaria acessar com uma conta gmail, mas ai fica a dúvida, não fui eu que gerei a chave, então o **SHA-1** vai ser diferente, e a conta do gmail, não teria que ser da pessoa que comprou a licença?

O ***X*** da questão é, já que tenho a chave, como faço para habilitar e fazer funcionar no meu app???

Segue a imagem de como está o App:

[image: Google Maps]

Comment: Eu tenho o Client ID e SKU, isso serve de alguma ajuda?

Comment: Se você está em um ambiente de teste, rodando o aplicativo diretamente da sua IDE para o seu aparelho, você deve utilizar uma chave diferente, pois a *keystore* utilizada é a de *debug*. Para essa chave que você recebeu funcionar corretamente em produção, você precisa gerar um **APK** do seu aplicativo **assinado** com a *keystore* que deu origem a esta chave. Talvez seja isto que esteja faltando pra você.

Comment: Estou executando direto da IDE, então eu devo utilizar meu e-mail e gerar uma nova chave para continuar o desenvolvimento? Quando você fala em meu aplicativo **assinado**, ta falando naquela assinatura para colocar no Google Play (Nunca postei app no google play). Não entendi quando você falou _keystore que deu origem a esta chave_ , a Keystore não seria a chave já? (OBS: Desculpe a ignorância, sou novo no mundo android)

Comment: Sim, para desenvolvimento você pode usar o console do Google que gera a chave utilizando qualquer conta. Quando digo assinado, é porque para gerar um APK de produção, você precisa de um arquivo *keystore*. Pela IDE é feito isso automaticamente, porém com a *keystore* de *debug*. O arquivo *keystore* possui o SHA1 que é utilizado para o console do Google gerar uma chave do Maps, essa que você coloca no Manifest. Dá uma olhada [nesta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8303/4337) minha resposta, veja se ajuda. Qual IDE você utiliza?

Comment: Acabei de gerar uma nova chave acessando o Console do Google, utilizei o `keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android` para pegar o SHA-1 e adicionar o meu projeto, gerei a chave... até ai tudo bem, agora utilizei a nova chave gerado pelo meu SHA-1, porém o mesmo erro, a mesma tela bege clara, não aparece o mapa, errei a onde? OBS: Estou usando direto pela IDE em desenvolvimento.

Comment: Aquele processo de excluir o aplicativo, dar clean no projeto e etc é importante nesta hora. Você fez tudo isso? Não sei o que poderia ser, o processo é esse mesmo. Tem alguma mensagem no `Logcat` sobre o mapa?

Comment: Desculpe-me pelo engano, esqueci de um detalhe, estou trabalhando na rede da empresa, estava sendo bloqueado pelo proxy, mudei de rede (Uma pessoal) e funcionou com essa nova chave, agora vou poder trabalhar e desenvolver, depois é só usar a chave que recebi (Comprado a licença business) na hora de publicar o google play, correto? Fora isso, deu certo!

Comment: Sim, mas para usar aquela chave, você precisa assinar seu APK com a mesma keystore que foi utilizada para gerar essa chave. Alguém que te deu essa chave do Google Maps gerou ela a partir de uma keystore, da mesma forma que você fez.

Comment: Ok @PauloRodrigues, ficarei atento a isso, irei solicitar essa keystore ao usuário que me mandou a chave, fico extremamente grato pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode gerar uma chave sem a SHA-1:
entre em console.developers.google.com e gere uma nova chave do GoogleMaps.
Se você deixar o campo da chave em branco, as solicitações de qualquer app do Android serão aceitas.